# Return a new array where each element is the number of smaller elements to the right of that element in the original input

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, functional-programming

The task:

> Given an array of integers, return a new array where each element in
>   the new array is the number of smaller elements to the right of that
>   element in the original input array.
>
> For example, given the array [3, 4, 9, 6, 1], return [1, 1, 2, 1, 0],
>   since:
>
> - There is 1 smaller element to the right of 3
> - There is 1 smaller element to the right of 4
> - There are 2 smaller elements to the right of 9
> - There is 1 smaller element to the right of 6
> - There are no smaller elements to the right of 1

```
const lst = [3, 4, 9, 6, 1];
```

My solutions:

```
const numberOfSmallerElem = lst => lst.map((x,i) => lst.slice(i + 1).reduce((acc,y) => y < x ? ++acc : acc, 0));    
console.log(numberOfSmallerElem(lst));

function numberOfSmallerElem2(lst) {
  for (let i in lst) {
    lst[i] = lst.slice(i).reduce((acc,y) => y < lst[i] ? ++acc : acc, 0);
  }
  return lst;
}
console.log(numberOfSmallerElem2(lst));

function numberOfSmallerElem3(lst) {
  const ret = [];
  for (let i = 0, len = lst.length; i < len - 1; i++) {
    const reference = lst[i];
    let counter = 0;
    for (let j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
      if(lst[j] < reference) { counter++; }
    }
    ret.push(counter);
  }
  ret.push(0);

  return ret;
}
console.log(numberOfSmallerElem3(lst));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Performance

The posted implementations are quadratic.
A log-linear solution exists.
Here's a hint:

> What if you insert values from right to left into a sorted list?

#### Avoid mutations in functional implementations

Can you spot the mutation on this line?

> ```
> const numberOfSmallerElem = lst => lst.map((x,i) => lst.slice(i + 1).reduce((acc,y) => y < x ? acc++ : acc, 0));
> ```

It's actually not easy to spot it when the line is so long!
I suggest to break it up, for readability.
And then eliminate the mutation.

> Replace `acc++` with `acc + 1`

Comment: So in functional programming you don't do increment/decrement, i.e. a++/a--?